# Use matching group after sed filter

Tags: regex, sed

Is it possible using sed to reuse the matched pattern in later commands?

I know it's possible when substituting but I'm just matching.

This is what I get when trying

```
> printf "hello world\ngood bye cruel world\n" | sed -re '/(.*)world/a found: \1'
hello world
found: 1
good bye cruel world
found: 1
```

I'd like for it to print

```
hello world
found: hello
good bye cruel world
found: good bye cruel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a replacement!

```
$ sed -r 's/(.*)world/&\nfound: \1/' < <(printf "hello world\ngood by cruel world\n")
hello world
found: hello 
good by cruel world
found: good by cruel
```

This captures whatever comes before `world` into `\1`. Then, it replaces it with `&` followed by a new line and `found:` + the captured group.

Since `&` holds the match, it prints the line again.

---

Find here the information about the `s//` command. From `man sed`:

> **Commands which accept address ranges**
>
> **s/regexp/replacement/**
>
> Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space.  If successful,
>   replace that portion matched with  replacement. The  replacement  may
>   contain the special character & to refer to that portion of the
>   pattern space which matched, and the special escapes \1 through \9 to
>   refer to the corresponding matching sub-expressions in the regexp.

Then, we see that `\a` doesn't allow us to use `\1` nor `&`:

> **Zero- or One- address commands**
>
> **a **
>
> text   Append text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a
>   backslash.

Comment: Cute, didn't know about &. Still, is it possible to do it "my way"?

Comment: I'm thinking I'd run multiple commands, all using the matched pattern.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand uhms, I am trying it but it seems to me that the captured groups are only available on the `s/ /` syntax.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand exactly, I checked `man sed` and it mentions this (or this is I understand from it). See my update.

Comment: Well, that's too bad but I guess you can't get everything :)

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand yes... I am pretty sure `perl` can do this in a more straight forward way. I am not very fluent on that language, though.